# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 99

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently new to python and PyCharm I am using the latest version of chrome on windows i keep getting this message (see below) when running the command:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com/")
```

Error:

```
Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 99
Current browser version is 95.0.4638.54 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Are you using Selenium WebDriver? Please add the relevant tags. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: i have a chrome driver and selenium installed

Comment: You were told to add the relevant tags! You should also, when you [edit] your question to include them, make significant improvements to your question, such that we have enough information to replicate your problem. Please take the site [tour], and take a look at [mcve] as well as the other linked pages within the [ask] guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 99
Current browser version is 95.0.4638.54 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=99.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=99.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/99.0.4844.51/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 99

- But you are using *chrome=95.0*

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=99.0* and the *chrome=95.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v99.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=99.0.4844.51/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=99.0* (as per [chromedriver=99.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/99.0.4844.51/notes.txt)).